# Custom login URL on asp.net loginstatus usercontrol

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have a website with two different sets of membership controls for different parts of the site.  The first one works fine.  There is a loginstatus control which handles the status of whether a user is logged in or not.  If not, it says 'Login' and links to 'Login.aspx' - as dictated in my web.config file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="yourAuthCookie" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" path="/" />
</authentication>
```

However, in a completely different part of the website there is a different loginstatus control, but the login URL for this control should be 'clientlogin.aspx'.  I just can't seem to get the loginstatus to link to 'clientlogin.asp' when the user is logged out.

Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: have you figured out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `LogoutPageUrl` property in the `LoginStatus` control?

Comment: I haven't but I'm sure from what I've read that LogoutPageUrl is the URL for the log OUT not the log IN.  I need the log in URL which doesn't seem to be a property on the control.